# How do I reset a user's password in EntityFramework Seed() method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

I want to reset the administrator's password in the Seed method of EntityFramework. However, because there is no OWIN context, I cannot initalize ApplicationUserManager to generate a token.

This is my code:

```
protected override void Seed(ModelUNRegister.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)

var userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
// How should I Initalize userManager.UserTokenProvider?

if (userManager.FindByName(AppSettings.InitalAdminAccount) == null)
{
    // Create user
}
else
{
    var adminUser = userManager.FindByName(AppSettings.InitalAdminAccount);
    // The following code throws error: IUserTokenProvider is not registered.
    string resetToken = userManager.GeneratePasswordResetToken(adminUser.Id);
    var result = userManager.ResetPassword(adminUser.Id, resetToken, AppSettings.InitalAdminPassword);

    if (!result.Succeeded) throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Concat(result.Errors));
}
```

I would like to know if there is other ways to generate a token to change the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need OWIN context, in your code you instantiated a `UserManager`. You have to show your `UserManager` code if you want suggestions about `IUserTokenProvider`
But you can update the password without generating tokens. Add method to `UserManager`

```
public Task<IdentityResult> ChangePassword(ApplicationUser user, string newPassword)
{
     var store = Store as IUserPasswordStore<ApplicationUser, string>;
     return UpdatePassword(store, user, newPassword);
}
```

and in your `Seed`

```
userManager.ChangePassword(adminUser, AppSettings.InitalAdminPassword);
```